# Android: get HTML text from XML

Tags: java, android, xml, saxparser

I have implemented in my app reading a XML. It works fine. But I want to format the text. I've tried in the XML:

```
 <monumento>
     <horarios><b>L-V:</b> 10 a 20<br/>S-D: 11 a 15</horarios>
     <tarifas>4000</tarifas>
 </monumento>
```

But the only thing I get if I put HTML character is that the text does not display in my app. 
I'll have many xml so that I will not always know where to place `<b>, <br/>`...

How I can do?

**Main**

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

```
        for (HorariosTarifasObj post : helper.posts) {
            builder.append(post.getHorarios());
        } 
        horario2.setText(builder.toString());

        builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (HorariosTarifasObj post : helper.posts) {
            builder.append(post.getTarifas());
        }
        tarifa2.setText(builder.toString());
```

**XMLReader**

```
public void get() {

    try {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

        XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
        reader.setContentHandler(this);

        InputStream inputStream = new URL(URL + monumento + ".xml").openStream();
        reader.parse(new InputSource(inputStream));

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    currTag = true;
    currTagVal = "";

    if (localName.equals("monumento")) {
        post = new HorariosTarifasObj();
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {

    currTag = false;

    if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("horarios")) {
        post.setHorarios(currTagVal);

    } else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("tarifas")) {
        post.setTarifas(currTagVal);

    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("monumento")) {
        posts.add(post);
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {

    if (currTag) {
        currTagVal = currTagVal + new String(ch, start, length);
        currTag = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp):

```
<monumento>
     <horarios><![CDATA[<b>L-V:</b> 10 a 20<br/>S-D: 11 a 15]]></horarios>
     <tarifas>4000</tarifas>
 </monumento>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XML, < and > characters are reserved for XML tags. You will need to protect them by replacing them with special encoding characters.

You can use `&gt;` for > and `&lt;` for <

(edit) Eomm answer is right, CDATA does this as well, and more simple

Also, to use HTML coding in TextView, you will need to use Html.fromHtml() method

For instance :

```
tarifa2.setText(Html.fromHtml(builder.toString()));
```

Comment: and the character **/**?

Comment: As far as I know, character / do not need encoding in XML

Comment: <horarios>&lt;b&gt;L-V&lt;/b&gt;</horarios> is correct?

Comment: no, but thanks for your help. The other answer is correct for me

Comment: OK. But did my Html.fromHtml method help ?

Comment: I guess that if you want to have your text displayed as HTML-formatted in your textview, you will need Html.fromHtml , but maybe there is other way I dont know, in that case, I'd be curious to know about it ?